# How to handle Simultaneous javascript xmlhttprequests?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, simultaneous-calls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [passing index from for loop to ajax callback function (javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077357/passing-index-from-for-loop-to-ajax-callback-function-javascript)

I've been a little confused with making xmlhttprequests, to different servers, in order to fetch some content..
Here is what I've written, but it seems that I'm mistaken at some point..

```
var URL = new Array();
URL[0] = "http://www.example1.com";
URL[1] = "http://www.example2.com";
URL[2] = "http://www.example3.com";
var nRequest = new Array();
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    nRequest[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
    nRequest[i].open("GET", URL[i], true);
    nRequest[i].onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
        if (nRequest[i].readyState === 4) {
            if (nRequest[i].status === 200) {
                console.log(nRequest[i].responseText);
                alert(nRequest[i].responseText);
            } else {
                console.log("Error", nRequest[i].statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    nRequest[i].send(null);
}
```

with this code on I.E.10 I get access denied on console..

If I remove array and use simple request, it operates as expected..

```
wRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
wRequest.open("GET", "http://www.example1.com", true);
wRequest.onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
    if (wRequest.readyState === 4) {
        if (wRequest.status === 200) {
            console.log(wRequest.responseText);
            alert(wRequest.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log("Error", wRequest.statusText);
        }
    }
};
wRequest.send(null);
```

But how am I supposed to trigger multiple 2-3 requests, and still not have problem with data handling..??

Comment: You cannot use AJAX to read data from a different domain.

Comment: I see a typo `wURL` --> `URL`, a closure issue `i` inside anonymous function and same origin policy issue.

Comment: why do i get data though from just a single domain?

Comment: [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) maybe?

Comment: I can't post a full answer (because the question is marked as a duplicate) but  you can store a value in the request object before sending the request `request.myParameter = myValue` --- and then access this value inside the listener function using the event parameter that you get there: `iEvent.target.myParameter`. Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem (ignoring the cross-domain issue that slebetman covered) is that when your ready state change callback is fired it is using the `i` variable from the containing scope which will be `3` after the loop completes. One way to fix that is as follows:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++){
   (function(i) {
      nRequest[i] = new XMLHttpRequest();
      nRequest[i].open("GET", URL[i], true);
      nRequest[i].onreadystatechange = function (oEvent) {
         if (nRequest[i].readyState === 4) {
            if (nRequest[i].status === 200) {
              console.log(nRequest[i].responseText);
              alert(nRequest[i].responseText);
            } else {
              console.log("Error", nRequest[i].statusText);
            }
         }
      };
      nRequest[i].send(null);
   })(i);
}
```

This introduces an immediately invoked function expression for each loop iteration such that the code inside the function has its own `i` - the magic of JS closures means that when the `onreadystatechange` function is called it will access the parameter `i` of the anonymous function (even though that function has completed), not the `i` of the outer scope, so the right `nRequest` element will be processed each time.

Also you had a typo on the `.open()` line where you said `wURL[i]` but should've had `URL[i]`.

Depending on what you plan to do with the response text I'm not sure that you need an array of requests at all: you could encapsulate the Ajax code into a function that takes a URL and a callback function as parameters, and then call that function in the loop...

Comment: that did the trick..!!! recently i had issue on another case with js' scope, and it seems that i faced it again...thank you very much..!!!

Comment: You're welcome. What I've shown is the minimal change to your existing code to make it work, but there are (in my opinion) nicer ways to structure the whole thing - probably outside the scope of this question though.

Comment: the typo, was just trying code to appear friendlier, than my original name handling of the variables...as for my respone text, i m just trying to make a mashup application, that collects data from 2-3 different sites, and gathers some specific information from each..that's why i thought it would be better to use an array..

Comment: could you elaborate, on the different approach that you suggest that i could handle the request?

Answer (score 1):

> making xmlhttprequests, to **different servers**

You cannot do that. XMLHttpRequest is only allowed to connect to the same domain that the page belongs to. This is called the *"same origin policy"*.

Google "same origin policy" or search for it here on SO to learn more.

Comment: thank you for your response, however, for some reason, i do get a response, when i trigger the single request..