# XMLHttpRequest in For-Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, xmlhttprequest

This code is supposed to loop through several webpages and find all the links on each page, listing them in console as it goes, but it seems to be listing only links from the very last webpage (fakeURL.com/735).

How I can get `console.log(url);` to work for every iteration, instead of just the last one (which is when i=735)?

```
for(i = 0; i <= 735; i += 15) 
{
    var xhrs = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrs.open("get", 'http://fakeURL.com/' + i, true);
    xhrs.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (xhrs.readyState == 4) 
        {
            $(xhrs.responseText).find('a').each(function()
            {           
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                console.log(url);                                               
            });
        }
    }
        xhrs.send();
}
```

Comment: You should see that : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26100329/xhr-response-with-for-loop-not-working/26100409#26100409
BTW, `$` seems to be jQuery, so why don't you use `$.ajax()` ?

Comment: Your code launches a whole bunch of ajax calls and then they all finish sometime later.  What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @jfriend00 I need the `console.log(url)` to happen during every iteration. Right now it only happens at the final iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're reusing the same `xhrs` variable for all your ajax calls.  Thus all the calls in play at once can't find the `xhrs` variable that belongs to their specific request when the `onreadystatechange` event fires.  Thus, they all end up looking at the `xhrs.readyState` from the last request so you only ever see the last request complete.

You should be able to switch to using `this` to refer to the request who generated the `onreadystatechange` event:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 735; i += 15) {
    var xhrs = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhrs.open("get", 'http://fakeURL.com/' + i, true);
    xhrs.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
        if (this.readyState == 4) 
        {
            $(this.responseText).find('a').each(function()
            {           
                var url = $(this).attr('href');
                console.log(url);                                               
            });
        }
    }
    xhrs.send();
}
```

As others have said, if `$` indicates that you're using jQuery, then `jQuery.ajax()` would likely  be a lot easier.