# How to pass an array through an XMLHttp Get request?

Tags: javascript, api, get, xmlhttprequest

I have an array that I want to using each value from it in my `GET` request. Something like this :

```
function something(){
    let test = ['something', 'other', 'test'];
    let httpRequest;
     function makeRequest(){
      httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
      httpRequest.onreadystatechange = test;
      for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
      (function(i){
      httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://test.com/' + test[i] , true);
      })()}
      httpeRequest.send();
   }
}
```

I keep getting undefined for `test[i]` though, and I'm not sure if this is how to correctly pass arrays through an `httpRequest` either. I will appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it you would have to create a for loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < test.length; i++){    
    makeRequest(test[i])
```

You have to create a new request for each item. Otherwise you could change your API to handle taking in an array of values and returning the data for them.

Comment: This works, but sometimes I get undefined, and when it does work I get my response objects in a json array, but I get two of the same objects for the last item in my array from my GET request and the error 'SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
'

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` for `test[i]` because you are not passing the parameter `i`, whereas you are expecting it as an argument in the *IIFE*:

```js
function something() {
  let test = ['something', 'other', 'test'];
  let httpRequest;

  function makeRequest() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest;
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = test;
    for (var i = 0; i < test.length; i++) {
      (function(i) {
        console.log(test[i]);
        httpRequest.open('GET', 'https://test.com/' + test[i], true);
         httpRequest.send(); // send request within loop
      })(i); // pass i here
    }
    // httpRequest.send();
  }
  
  makeRequest(); // call for testing
}

something(); // call for testing
```

Other thing, there are some flaws in the code, like:

1. You might need to send the request `httpRequest.send()` within the loop if you want multiple calls
2. `onreadystatechange` should define a `function`; assigning an array doesn't make sense
3. For simultaneous calls, you might have to create multiple `XMLHttpRequest` request. Right now you are only creating one and changing the url, these will just get aborted.

[Checkout more detailed answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445809/how-to-handle-simultaneous-javascript-xmlhttprequests)