# reference to iterator is lost when inner $.getJSON is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to go through all over `highchart` serieses and at the same time perform ajax to the server. Let's see the code below

```
var url = './sheet';
for(var k = 0; k < chart.series.length; k++) {                      
    console.log(chart.series[k]);
    $.getJSON(url).done(function (data){
        if (data.length) {                              
            console.log(chart.series[k]);
        }
    });
}
```

I am not sure what is the problem with the code above. As you can see the reference to var `k` is lost when `jQuery.getJSON` is done. Appreciate if you can help me. Thank you

Comment: `getJSON` is an async call, so the loop moves past the current index while your data call is in progress

Comment: See [How do javascript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Hrm.. I know this is a duplicate, but I can't decide on the best one... maybe [this one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077357/passing-index-from-for-loop-to-ajax-callback-function-javascript)

Comment: after closure the ajax, i've been hit by **Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**.

Comment: @MuhaiminAbdul What are you trying to do? That error usually means there's infinite/too much recursion somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is asynchronous, wrap it in a closure so it retains it's value in the loop.

```
var url = './sheet';
for(var k = 0; k < chart.series.length; k++) {                      
    (function(k){
        console.log(chart.series[k]);
        $.getJSON(url).done(function (data){
            if (data.length) {                              
                console.log(chart.series[k]);
            }
        });
    })(k);
}
```

As Jason referenced in the comments, [learn how closures work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).