# Array gives errors after JSON function

Tags: javascript, json, twitch

I'm trying to check if the twitch stream is online or offline and if so change a background colour. If i check without the array and just put in the name it works, but with the array it doesn't (I don't have a lot of knowledge of JSON).

```
function test() {
  var twitchChannels = ["imaqtpie", "summit1g", "tyler1", "greekgodx"];

  for (var i = 0; i < twitchChannels.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + " " + twitchChannels[i]);

    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + twitchChannels[i] + '?client_id=XXXX', function(channel) {
      console.log(i + " " + twitchChannels[i]);

      if (channel["stream"] == null) {
        console.log("Offline: " + twitchChannels[i])
        document.getElementById(twitchChannels[i]).style.backgroundColor = "red";
      } else {
        console.log("Online: " + twitchChannels[i])
        document.getElementById(twitchChannels[i]).style.backgroundColor = "green";
      }

    });
  }

}
```

Error: http://prntscr.com/i6qj51 inside the red part is what happens inside of json fuction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing index from for loop to ajax callback function (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077357/passing-index-from-for-loop-to-ajax-callback-function-javascript)

Comment: `$.getJSON` is async, as of that the value of `i` in your callback won't be what you expect that it would be. Either use `let i` or the method descriped in the duplicate.

Comment: See also [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486) and [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite weak since you didn't manage the [callback](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)  of every get you make.
Also you didn't check if:

```
document.getElementById(twitchChannels[i])
```

is null, since the exception clearly stated that you can't get :

```
.style.backgroundColor
```

from nothing.

Basic check VanillaJS:

```
if(!document.getElementById("s"))
  console.log('id ' + twitchChannels[i] +  ' not found in dom')
else 
  console.log('id ' + twitchChannels[i] +  ' found in dom')
```

Also consider mixing JQuery with VanillaJS extremely bad practice; use proper JQuery method to access [dom element by ID](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) .

Comment: Your answer does not contain any ingformation how the problem can be solved.

Comment: add logic to test dom VanillaJS

Comment: _"mixing JQuery with VanillaJS extremely bad practice"_ : It's not bad practice at all, if you know what you are doing.

Comment: In the given code `document.getElementById(twitchChannels[i])` will always return `null`. The test if `document.getElementById(twitchChannels[i])` is `null` is good practice, but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @AngelPolitis: well it's arguable. For my experience in big project that should be cause of great problems. Especially on long term ones.
 t.niese: https://jsfiddle.net/Black_Jack/LsL3pmLm/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should pass twitchChannel to the function because the var i is changing, this is an issue like others already mentioned: [Preserving variables inside async calls called in a loop.](http://www.javascriptcookbook.com/article/Preserving-variables-inside-async-calls-called-in-a-loop/)

Comment: The test in the loop is _less then_(`<`)  and not _less or equal then_ (`<=`), so `twitchChannels.length-1` would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you made some ajax call in a cicle, but the ajax calls are async.

Whey you get the first response, the cicle is already completed, and i==4, that is outside the twitchChannels size: that's why you get "4 undefined" on your console.

You can change your code in such way:

```
function test() {
    var twitchChannels = ["imaqtpie", "summit1g", "tyler1", "greekgodx"];

    for (var i = 0; i < twitchChannels.length; i++) {
        executeAjaxCall(twitchChannels[i]);
    }
}
function executeAjaxCall(twitchChannel){
    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + twitchChannel + '?client_id=XXXX', function(channel) {
        console.log(twitchChannel);

        if (channel["stream"] == null) {
            console.log("Offline: " + twitchChannel)
            $('#'+twitchChannel).css("background-color", "red");
        } else {
            console.log("Online: " + twitchChannel)
            $('#'+twitchChannel).css("background-color", "green");
        }

    });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When `console.log(i + " " + twitchChannels[i]);` is called inside the callback function, the variable `i` has already been set to 4, and accessing the 4th element of array `twitchChannels` gives `undefined` since the array has only 4 elements.

This is because `$.getJSON` is a shorthand *Ajax* function which, as the name suggests, executes your requests *asynchronously*.  So what actually happened is, based on the output you provided,

1. The loop is executed 4 times, and four Ajax requests have been sent.
2. The loop exits; `i` is already set to 4 now.
3. The ajax requests return; the callbacks are called, but the `i` value they see is now 4.

You can change the `console.log` inside your callback to something like `console.log(i + " " + twitchChannels[i] + " (inside callback)");` to see this more clearly.

The correct result can be obtained by binding the current value of `i` to the closure.

```
function test() {
  var twitchChannels = ["imaqtpie", "summit1g", "tyler1", "greekgodx"];

  function make_callback(index) {
    return function (channel) {
        console.log(index + " " + twitchChannels[index]);

        if (channel["stream"] == null) {
          console.log("Offline: " + twitchChannels[index])
          document.getElementById(twitchChannels[index]).style.backgroundColor = "red";
        } else {
          console.log("Online: " + twitchChannels[index])
          document.getElementById(twitchChannels[index]).style.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < twitchChannels.length; i++) {
    console.log(i + " " + twitchChannels[i]);

    $.getJSON('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + twitchChannels[i] + '?client_id=XXXX', make_callback(i));
  }

}
```